# Best architecture to share large files among microservices

Tags: nfs, microservices, data-sharing

I am about to start re-designing an old monolithic software with a microservices-oriented architecture (educational purposes). To give a bit of context, the old software runs on a powerful server that performs the following operations:

1. Receives batch data (binary file) from a producer.
2. Accumulates batch data from each producer.
3. Periodically, execute a batch operation over each producer's accumulated data, and store the result (another binary file).

Now, I want to create a separated microservice for this batch operation.  I would like to have this microservice executed in dozens of machines in paralell, so that I can process a big amount of producers.

Each microservice instance will receive a binary file with each producer's data and output another binary file. The problem is that these files can be big (e.g. each producer may produce 20Mb of accumulated data). I came across several ways of dealing with this but I am not convinced by any of them:

1. Send the binary data among microservices using HTTP calls. I did not try it but it does not seem reasonable.
2. Store all the data in a central data repository from where each microservice can download it. Maybe I could use some sort of NFS, but I am not sure if that's a good option. Also, doesn't this go against the microservices philosophy?
3. Have a copy of all the data near each microservice. I am afraid I'll eventually run into consistency problems.

What do you believe is the best option (if any)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your microservice R can be described as "receives per-producer batch data and exposes a REST API to list, manage and retrieve this data".

This service will need to keep this data in a store (have you thought about a database? Postgresql can store up to 2 gig size blobs), and for architectural reasons I would recommend that the contents are not exposed via actual files but via HTTP (did you know that you can retrieve arbitrary parts of a file using HTTP?).

This allows you to stream the files (no need to have the whole file in memory) over the network, have access controls if necessary, logging access and usage times etc.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I see with a central data-storage is that I will have thousands of batch-workers (>100 starting each second). That would mean >100 read-requests per second to the service (each one to download something like 20Mb). I believe network speed can be a bottleneck soon... =(

Comment: Then you have a more interesting use case :-D. What's the read-write ratio (how many times does an blob from a producer get read from the same / different clients)? Is the blob retention lifetime known or indefinite? Can you vertically split by producer? Does one client for one processing step need to take data from multiple producers?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. a) The system is currently generating 1000 blobs/hour, of 3MB each (average). Once generated, blob goes in a FIFO job queue, and is used to update previous results (another blob, typically 20Mb size). This blob is also stored and sent to other workers that update their state based on this data. b) Blob retention is indefinite. I don's understand, c) I don't understand the concept of "vertically split", sorry =(, d) no, clients only process data from one producer (everything is very sequential). Thanks!

Comment: You can split your microservice into different physical servers, so that each server holds & processes blobs for a small number of providers. However as your storage needs increase by 1 TB every 10 days, I assume you have either a SAN expert on hand or use something like S3; in which case I'd say just pass S3 URLs to clients for retrieval.